# Spring - concurrency task

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

We are using spring in our web application.

Consider the following example:

```
public ResultDTO getAllHappyFaces(Face[] faces) {

   ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();

   for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        if (calculateIfHappyFace(faces[i]))
               result.add(i);
   }

  return result;

}
```

Now, we would like to make this process concurrent.
Whats our best way of doing that using spring's standard module for executing multithreaded tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haver to use @Async annotation

```
     @Async
     void doSomething() {
        // this will be executed asynchronously
     }
```

Look the documentation of Spring http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But i was thinking about using a spring thread pool, the @Async annotation only assures that a new thread will execute the code, not creating multiple threads and provide work accordingly

Comment: You can provide the same than Executor framework.  <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>

<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>   
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>}   Read the documentation